# Matching float and string value in javascript not matched

Tags: javascript, html, floating-point, integer

I am using this code

```
if(total == balance)
{
alert("test ok");
}
else
{
alert("test failed");
}
```

here `total=10;` and `balance=10.00;` but the result is "test failed".

Comment: `balance==10.00` - I'm sure it is not. It's either something like `10.000000000001` or `"10.00"`.

Comment: Is it need to do at the time of assign????

Comment: We'll need to see your variable assignments.

Comment: Works fine here is that's the exact definition of your vars http://jsfiddle.net/35p5oLmr/

Comment: @georg:  `"10.00"` should be no problem, assuming `total` is a Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... I may not be exactly correct, but I think total is taken as an integer and balance is taken as a decimal. Try the `===` function instead of the `==` function.

The `===` function *converts* the values and then checks them.
So checking if a value is `true` or `false` depending on whether it is 0 or 1 requires the `===` operator to convert both into the same type of values.

And the `==` function just checks whether two values are equal, just by looking at the present value of it. No conversion. So if I want to check the values of two `int` values, I will use `==`.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

One is by changing either the total into a decimal, by giving it a value of 10.00 with a decimal or changing the balance into an int by giving it a value of 10, without the decimal places.

The other is the better one, and you just have to replace your `==` with a `===`. So your code would look like this:

```
if (total === balance) {
    window.alert("test ok");
} else {
    window.alert("test failed");
}
```

Comment: i am using one function call here that have getValue1(), getValue2() and new_value = getValue1(); old_value = getValue2(); total = new_value + old_value; here any type conversion problem is possible.

Comment: Then try float.parse()-ing all the values, maybe?